# Quantile regression in SAS vs Python

Tags: python, sas, statsmodels, quantile-regression

Given this dataset

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'year':[2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002],'metric':[2,3,4,5,6,12,13,14,15,16,22,23,24,25,26]})
```

running quantile regression for the 0.5 quantile using the Statsmodels package

```
model=smf.quantreg('metric ~ year', df)
result=model.fit(q=0.5, vcov='robust', kernel='epa', bandwidth='hsheather', max_iter=1000, p_tol=1e-06)
```

results in this outcome:

[image]

SAS' PROC QUANTREG, however, produces
[image]

I'm confused by the Statsmodels' coefficient. Given that the medians for the 3 years are 4, 14, and 24 shouldn't the coefficient be 10 like SAS'? Changing the kernel and bandwidth [options](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.quantile_regression.QuantReg.fit.html#statsmodels-regression-quantile-regression-quantreg-fit) doesn't affect it.

I do see the "condition number is large" message for Statsmodels. If I were to [address](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/243000/cause-of-a-high-condition-number-in-a-python-statsmodels-regression) this by normalizing the dataset such that the years are 0, 0.5, and 1 then I do get a coefficient of 20 which is what SAS produces as well.

Why does statsmodels producs a different coefficient for non-normalized data?

Comment: high condition number lowers precision and creates problems in the computations. Most likely this causes convergence problems in the iteration loop. (It looks like statsmodels quantile regression is not very robust if model/data is not well behaved.)

Comment: Statsmodels does not do any internal transformation like scaling of the data to improve optimization.  It's up to the user to provide well behaved data. Whether this will change in statsmodels remains undecided. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1131